# How to make the StreamTokenizer to recognize chars blending with numbers as Words

Tags: java, object, lexer

How can I make the StreamTokenizer recognize characters blending with numbers as words?

I'm currently developing a calculator which uses Reverse Polish Notation.
Everything works just fine except when the `StreamTokenizer` encounters something like `354a` or `1b`. What I want here is that the `StreamTokenizer` sees it as a word and not as a number followed by a word. Here is my code:

```
sT = new StreamTokenizer(f);
sT.resetSyntax();
sT.eolIsSignificant(false);
sT.wordChars('a', 'z');
sT.wordChars('A', 'Z');
sT.whitespaceChars(32, 32);
sT.parseNumbers();

while (sT.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
    int ttype = sT.ttype;
if (ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
      calc.empile(sT.nval);
}       
else{
  if (!calc.stack.isEmpty()) {
    switch (ttype) {
    case '+':
          calc.plus();
      break;
    case '-':
      calc.moins();
      break;
    case '*':
      calc.mult();
      break;
    case '/':
      calc.div();
      break;
      }
    }
  }
  sT.nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this answer: [StreamTokenizer splits up 001_to_003 into two tokens; how can I prevent it from doing so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167872/streamtokenizer-splits-up-001-to-003-into-two-tokens-how-can-i-prevent-it-from)

But I think that you could just do this: [How do I sidestep TT_NUMBER from StreamTokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856750/how-do-i-sidestep-tt-number-from-streamtokenizer)

...and then try to parse your doubles or ints by iterating the result.

Hope it helps, though there is no clear answer to your question here...

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm very sorry for the long absence but i'm under pressure in my school with several projects.
I've read these two topics and realized how broken was this class^^
It was a mistake trying to use it instead of a scanner, and since my 
work validates on my teachers testSuite, even with the error detailed above, i've decide to let go^^